# Nhibernate Get and Load

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am fixing a codebase using NHibernate and I found out that instead of using Get or Load to find entities by ID they were using a query.

Like :

> `session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).Add(Expression.AllEq(propertyNameValues)).List<T>();`

where the propertyNameValues is a IDictionnary containing "ID" and the id value.

Trying to replace it with :

> `session.Get<T>(id);`

Nhibernate throws a No Persister found for my class.

But there is obviously one as the first method works, my google-fu only found links where it was people forgetting to set the given hbm to embedded ressources or the mapping assembly in the nhibernate configuration.

I tried Get(id) , Get(typeof(T),id), Get("ClassName",id) all throw same error.

Here is the mapping as requested (thank you)

```
<class name="Domain.Customers.Customer, Domain" table="Customer" lazy ="true">
    <id name="ID" column="id" access="field.lowercase-underscore" type="int">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
```

This is the mapping of one class but it's generic for all my entitites.

Thanks for any pointer.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, I've edited my post accordingly, hope it helps.

Comment: Well seem related to the fact they call this method via reflection and it's in the Generic class. So I decided to let it call it the wrong way in most place, and simply override the base method in classes where it's called often. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is "ID" mapped as the identity property for the object? As Mark said, we will need to see the mapping to give a better answer.